# Nginx or php-fpm error?

Tags: nginx, vps, php-fpm

I found my vps nginx error log like this

```
2013/04/06 03:28:04 [alert] 8557#0: mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, 5242880000) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory)
2013/04/06 04:05:30 [alert] 10299#0: mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, 5242880000) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory)
2013/04/06 04:05:58 [alert] 10786#0: mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, 5242880000) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory)
```

What is the caused?
ram about 16GB

Regards

Comment: what's your php max memory setting in php.ini?

Comment: I have the same issue, but my server is only 256MB, and it worked for couple of years before last upgrade. I reduced the php-fpm memory to 64Mb, still have the same error in nginx. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem.

**First** check you shared memory settings.

```
echo $((`cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax` / 1024 / 1024))Mb
```

In my case I had only 32Mb.

If you want increase this memory (with your server's memory it could be a good idea), check this [documentation](http://www.rwitkop.com/VistA/ConfigureSysctl4Cache.html)

**Second**, check your nginx proxy settings - `proxy_cache_path` parameter. In my case it was inside of `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/my-site.com` but you may found it on any file inside `/etc/nginx/` folder.

I had this line: `fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:500m inactive=60m;`, which required **500Mb!** of shared memory.

So, change the keys_zone memory part to maximum of your shared memory. You may read more information about `fastcgi_cache_path` parameter [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_path)

Remember to restart nginx after.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, I advise you to provide more information about free memory you have and nginx version.

It seems you do not have additional **~5G** memory on your server.

Try to decrease shared memory size in your nginx config server (check **proxy_cache_path** in nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it needs more shared memory?  You might look at increasing the kernel.shmmax property in /etc/sysctl.conf It's probably not there by default but you can

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
```

to see what it is now.

Answer (score 0):

My ram is 16gb but used by mysql, php-fpm and nginx about 14gb. This massaage appear when i restart nginx. Because nginx cache at /dev/shm about 5gb, nginx wan't restart if memory less then nginx cache size. this solved after restart php-fpm and free ram about 11gb.
Thanks for your constribute

Comment: I did restart of php-fpm but nothing changed, any other idea?